# Which packages I should use for this table?

Tags: tables

How I can add a table with this style. I take the example from [here](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tablestyles/tablestyles.pdf)

[image]

I have the code but without any further instructions which packages I should import.

```
\colorlet{grayline}{gray!70}
\definecolor{blueline}{rgb}{0,0.27,0.55}
\begin{table}
\tablestyle
% Overwriting style, instead of defining a new one
\renewcommand{\tbegin}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
\renewcommand{\tbody}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
\renewcommand{\tend}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{%
l!{\coloredvline{grayline}}
CC!{\coloredvline{grayline}}
CC!{\coloredvline{grayline}}
C
}
\theadstart
\thead header &
\multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}
c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
\multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}
c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}c}
{header}
%
\tabularnewline
\tbody
%
description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
\tend
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\usepackage{tabularx}` in your preamble.

Comment: I added them but did not work

Comment: You can try the code be yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load only

```
\usepackage{tablestyles} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

and make some corrections of the code. (The example in your link does not work correctly.).

[image: c]

This is the complete code. (`xcolor` is loaded by `tablestyles`}

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tablestyles} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tabularx} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\colorlet{grayline}{gray!70}
\definecolor{blueline}{rgb}{0,0.27,0.55}
\setuptablecolor{head}{gray!75}
 
\begin{table}
\tablestyle
\renewcommand{\tlinetop}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
\renewcommand{\tlinemid}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
\renewcommand{\tlinebottom}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
    \begin{tabular}{l!{\coloredvline{grayline}}C{0.15\textwidth}
                    C{0.15\textwidth}!{\coloredvline{grayline}}C{0.15\textwidth}
                    C{0.15\textwidth}!{\coloredvline{grayline}}C{0.15\textwidth}
            }
        \theadstart%        
        \thead header &
        \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}
        c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
        \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}
        c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}c}
        {header}
        \tabularnewline
        \tbody
        description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
        description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
        description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
        description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
        \tend
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Table with colored vertical and horizontal lines}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

For newcomers, I used `tabularray` and it is so easy. I would recommend using this [guidance](https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf), they have a lot of examples. I designed the same question I asked with the following short, and clear code, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
colspec={cccccccc},
rowspec={Q[gray!20]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]}, 
vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5}}
header  & header & header & header & header & header & header & header\\
1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
   \end{tblr}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The example you found in [CTAN-tablestyles](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tablestyles/tablestyles.pdf) for `Listing 10` producing `Table 3` uses not only `tabularx` but also the following `newcolumntype`:

- `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}`

This command asks for a parameter to the column type `p`. The given example didn't have any.

To find the root of the problem I proceed like this:

- removed the `!{\coloredvline{grayline}}` and use only column types `l` and `C` -> Didn't work.
- changed all column types to the basics `l` and `c`. Worked. Result named `op1`:
  [image]
- Added some measures to `C`. Worked. Result named `op2`:
  [image]
- Added `!{\coloredvline{grayline}}` to `l`. Worked. Result named `op3`:
  [image]
- Added `!{\coloredvline{grayline}}` after the correct `C` columns. Worked. Result named `op4`:
  [image]

Please, notice I didn't add precise column's length. Instead I just added the basic needed information to run the code. This whole issue is a nice remainder of the reasons why MWE (Minimal Working Examples) are the standard procedure to test anything new. Although there is an example of `\newcolumntype{C}` at `Listing 15` of `tablestyles`, it is after the example that used it, and this makes things are little bit more complicated to understand.

The complete MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tablestyles}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{grayline}{gray!70}
\definecolor{blueline}{rgb}{0,0.27,0.55}

\begin{table}
  \tablestyle
    % Overwriting style, instead of defining a new one
    \renewcommand{\tbegin}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
    \renewcommand{\tbody}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
    \renewcommand{\tend}{\coloredhline{blueline}}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{%
% l CC CC C % Does not work
%  l cc cc c %op1
% l C{1cm}C{1.5cm} C{1.2cm}C{1cm} C{1cm} %op2
% l!{\coloredvline{grayline}} C{1cm}C{1.5cm} C{1.2cm}C{1cm} C{1cm} %op3
  l!{\coloredvline{grayline}} C{1cm}C{1.5cm} !{\coloredvline{grayline}}C{1.15cm}C{1cm} !{\coloredvline{grayline}} C{1cm} %op4
    }
    \theadstart
    \thead
    header &
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead} c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead} c!{\coloredvline{grayline}}}{header} &
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{\tablecolor{head}}\thead}c}{header}
    \tabularnewline
    \tbody
    description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
    description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
    description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
    description & 0,3 & 0,35 & 0,5 & 0,65 & 0,80 \\
    \tend  
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

#### Edit

As pointed out by Simon Dispa, in order to achieve the blue color lines replace the command `\theadstart` with `\tbegin`.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the topline is not blue.

Comment: @Simon Dispa, Yes, I totally agree. I reproduced the code from tablestyles correcting only the non functional parts. I've seen you changed `\tbegin`, `\tbody` and `\tend` to `\tlinetop`, `\tlinemid` and `\tlinebottom` respectively in order to achieve the correct colors. This issue comes from the original code of tablestyles. I didn't even realize the error within line colors. Thanks.